# Has anybody actually already played Dungeons The Dragoning 40000 7th Edition?

Tags: dungeons-the-dragoning

Released as an April Fools joke, [Dungeons The Dragoning 40000 7th Edition](http://lawfulnice.blogspot.com/2011/04/dungeons-dragoning-11.html) is a parody and conglomerate of many established roleplaying games, including but not limited to: D&D, WoD, 7th Sea, Exalted, Deadlands, WH 40k and many more.

While obviously not intended as a "real" rpg (it even says so in the credits) some elements and aspects of the game do sound interesting.

- Has anybody already tried running it or at least taken a closer look at the game's mechanics?
- How does it play, especially considering the strange combination of WoD's stat system with Lot5R's Roll-and-Keep dice system?
- What are the game's party dynamics (if such a thing exists in that system)
- What style of play is best suitable for the system (heroic, grim'n'gritty, ...)?

Comment: Didn't know this existed. +1 for making my day

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a pretty solid system. It's a bit on the rules-heavy side, but it has no real fundamental flaws, and the minor flaws are being ironed out.
It may say that it's not real at the end, but as far as I know that's for legal reasons, as there is a complete (and entirely real) set of rules and fluff. It is best for heroic games and games that are at least a little bit beer-and-pretzels. If you can't abide light-heartedness, you won't like it, but anyone else will probably enjoy it fine.
Party dynamic is based on what people want to play, there aren't really proscribed roles like D&D or Shadowrun.

Answer (score 9):

I was a playtester for the game, so I can attest that it is in fact playable. There has been a HUGE demand for a more polished version along with more material. The creator has started [a blog](http://lawfulnice.blogspot.com/) to help people keep track of the progress of things, as well as an IRC chat:

> Server: irc.rizon.net
>   Channel: #dtdchat

Comment: Info from experience is always good. Welcome to the site, Ampris.

Answer (score 2):

L5R's stat system and WWG's stat system both scale pretty much the same 
1: minimum human
2: average human
5: peak human without magical intervention
10: peak human with magical intervention.

Therefore, the same basic mechanic should work just as well in the very similarly scaled DtD40K. And it works VERY well in L5R... for heroic gaming, at least.